# react-native : how to make animation header active when scrollview passes a certain point

Tags: react-native

I have an animation header and I could change the height by scrolling the view.

**My question** I want the animation to start when scrollview passes a certain point.

In the `gif`, animation is `immediately activated` when I scroll the view. I want the animation to start when when I start the see the `yellow view`.

[image]

This is my code:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  this.state = {
       scrollY:new Animated.Value(0)
    }
  }

  render() {

    const HeaderHeight = this.state.scrollY.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 200],
      outputRange: [200, 0],
      extrapolate: 'clamp'
    })

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Animated.View style={{width:'100%', height:HeaderHeight, backgroundColor:'red', justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}>
        <Text>Animated Header </Text>
        </Animated.View>

       <ScrollView
        scrollEventThrottle={16}
        onScroll={Animated.event([{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: this.state.scrollY } } }])}
        style={{width:'100%', backgroundColor:'gray'}}>
        <View style={{width:'100%', height:500, backgroundColor:'blue'}}/>
        <View style={{width:'100%', height:500, backgroundColor:'green'}}/>
        <View style={{width:'100%', height:500, backgroundColor:'yellow'}}/>
       </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I get the y position like the code below.

```
  onLayout = (e) => {
        this.setState({
          y: e.nativeEvent.layout.y
        })
      }
```

In my scrollview I apply it like this.

```
<ScrollView
                onLayout={this.onLayout}/>
```

Then I could conditionally use the `y` position to activate the animation.